# Is it possible to convert DataRow to arraylist?

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataRow. Is there a way to convert it into an arraylist? I need to convert it to an arraylist because I want to pass it to a function which compares two arrays and returns false if they are not the same.

```
foo(datarow, arraylist)


Public Function foo(ByVal arr1 as Arraylist, ByVal arr2 as ArrayList) as Boolean

    Compare and return false if they are not the same

End Function
```

So, how do I convert datarow to arraylist so that I can pass it to that function.

Comment: what is/will be in the other arraylist?

Comment: `ArrayList` is obsolete and shouldn't be used unless necessary.

Comment: @Plutonix Collection of strings.

Comment: add each row arraylist and convert lists to collection and use remove compare

Comment: Why don't you compare values of cells of the `DataRow` to values or entries in the `ArrayList`? You don't have to convert containers to the same type.

Comment: each arraylist element is a string collection? yuck!  this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @DourHighArch Thanks for the reponse. I think that will solve my problem.

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry. I am a beginner in vb.net.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the implementation of that method because `ArrayList` is almost certainly the wrong type for those parameters.  As suggested, you shouldn't be using `ArrayList` at all if you're targeting .NET 2.0 or higher.  Depending on the implementation, those parameters should be arrays, `List(Of T)`, `IList(Of T)`, `IList`, `IEnumerable(Of T)` or `IEnumerable`.  You may well be able to simply pass the `DataRow` itself in that case or its `ItemArray` property.

Comment: John and Plutonix make good points; this sounds like a very strange thing to do. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24420851/edit) your question to include what you have (not just the types) and what you plan to do with them. You may be going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that you should only convert to ArrayList if necessary, but you certainly can.

```
    Dim al As New ArrayList
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("f")
    dt.Columns.Add("n")

    Dim dr As DataRow
    dr = dt.NewRow
    dr.Item(0) = "First"
    dr.Item(1) = "Name"
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns

            al.Add(row.Item(column.ColumnName))

        Next

        MessageBox.Show(al.Item(0).ToString & " " & al.Item(1).ToString)

    Next
```